# Code Blocks stopped while writing code or just after open it

Tags: 16.04, command-line, software-center, code-blocks

Code blocks 13.12 is installed in Ubuntu 16.04. After open code blocks it was just close without giving any warning some time while writing code. Now i can't even write any code when i start writing after 3 or 4 line it's stopped in similar manner. 
i try to remove it from Ubuntu Software center. It removed and i don't find it by search in my computer. but when i search code blocks in Ubuntu Software center there is only option for remove, though i already remove it.

then i try to install using terminal, it installed but the same problem remain.

Comment: Run the application from the terminal so you can see the error output if there is any. Otherwise find out if Code Blocks has an application specific log file. (This feels like a problem more geared toward the Code Blocks community than the AskUbuntu community).

Comment: okay, but seems okay after run from terminal.